# Has anyone successfully gotten Microsoft.ML output on Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: c#, c++, macos, visual-studio-2019, microsoft.ml

All,

From a few hours of research, I have some doubt many people if any have gotten Microsoft.ML working on their Macs. When the trainers (I tried a few) try to consume the data the below error is thrown:

System.DllNotFoundException: CpuMathNative assembly: type: member:(null) at (wrapper managed-to-native) Microsoft.ML.Internal.CpuMath.Thunk.SumSqU(single*,int)

I tried a few different things that have worked for others on Windows machines. From what I can tell it is either:

1. https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/3764 <-- Project or solution not configured for x64. ✓
2. [ML.Net sentimental analysis prediction of comments not working in ASP.NET MVC web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890426/ml-net-sentimental-analysis-prediction-of-comments-not-working-in-asp-net-mvc-we) <-- Bugs in Microsoft.ML 1.4.0+. ✓
3. https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/1999 <-- Not having the Visual Studio C++ extension installed. X

Since Visual Studio for Mac doesn't have a C++ extension does anyone have a possible work around for this? Any and all ideas welcome!

Many Thanks,

kdizzle

Comment: You could write your own from scratch in c# - which seems like it would be supported by your set up. However you never know about weird issues you may have with trying that, even the current top tutorials on how to do that in C# are not bug free pieces of code. One guy just commented his trainer method out aha...